How to handle multiple field updates in a form with GraphQL mutations in React?
I'm building a React form where I need to update multiple settings using GraphQL mutations. However, I want to optimize the process by calling the API only once to update all fields at once, instead of making separate calls for each individual field. Here's the code I have so far:
import { ADMIN_SETTING_ALL, ADMIN_SETTING_UPDATE } from '@/graphql/setting';
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { FormInput, FormSelect2 } from '@/components/form';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { RadioGroup } from "@radix-ui/react-radio-group";
import { RadioGroupItem } from "@/components/ui/radio-group";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import HelmetWrapper from '@/components/helmet-wrapper';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'; // Import the Button
import { FormLabel } from '@/components/ui/form';
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Card, CardContent, CardDescription, CardHeader, CardTitle } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormMessage } from '@//components/ui/form';
import { Input } from '@//components/ui/input';
import { ADMIN_SETTING_FILE_UPDATE } from '@//graphql/setting';
import {PlusCircle} from "lucide-react";
import Pagination from "@//components/graphql-pagination/index.jsx";
import {CustomCard} from "@//components/common/index.js";

function manageOptions(options) {
    const parsedOptions = JSON.parse(options);
    return parsedOptions?.map((option) => ({
        label: option,
        value: option,
    }));
}

export default function AppSetting({ group, title, description }) {
    const { data: generalData, error } = useQuery(ADMIN_SETTING_ALL, {
        variables: { group: group },
    });

    const { toast } = useToast();
    const form = useForm({
        defaultValues: {},
    });
    const { formState } = form;

    const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        if (generalData) {
            const defaultValues = generalData?.settings?.reduce((acc, field) => {
                acc[field.name] = field.value || '';
                return acc;
            }, {});

            setSelectedValues(defaultValues);
            form.reset(defaultValues);
        }
    }, [generalData, form]);

    const handleRadioChange = (name, value) => {
        setSelectedValues((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [name]: value,
        }));
        form.setValue(name, value);
    };

    const [UpdateSettings] = useMutation(ADMIN_SETTING_UPDATE, {
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            toast({
                title: 'Success',
                description: 'Settings updated successfully.',
            });
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            toast({
                title: 'Error',
                description: 'Failed to update settings, try again.',
            });
        },
    });

    const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState(null);

    const [UpdateSettingsFile] = useMutation(ADMIN_SETTING_FILE_UPDATE, {
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            toast({
                title: 'Success',
                description: 'Settings updated successfully.',
            });
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            toast({
                title: 'Error',
                description: 'Failed to update settings, try again.',
            });
        },
    });

    async function onSubmit(data) {
        const formData = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
            id: generalData?.settings?.find(setting => setting.name === key)?.id,
            value: data[key],
            type: generalData?.settings?.find(setting => setting.name === key)?.type,
        }));

        const validFormData = formData.filter(({ id }) => id);

        if (validFormData.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        let updateErrors = [];

        try {
            for (const { id, value, type } of validFormData) {
                try {
                    if (type === "file") {
                        await UpdateSettingsFile({
                            variables: {
                                id: parseInt(id),
                                input: { value: thumbnail },
                            },
                        });
                    } else {
                        await UpdateSettings({
                            variables: {
                                id: parseInt(id),
                                input: { value },
                            },
                        });
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error updating setting:", error.message);
                    updateErrors.push(`Failed to update ${value}`);
                }
            }

            if (updateErrors.length > 0) {
                toast({
                    title: 'Error',
                    description: `Some settings failed to update: ${updateErrors.join(', ')}`,
                });
            } else {
                toast({
                    title: 'Success',
                    description: 'Settings updated successfully.',
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error updating settings:", error.message);
            toast({
                title: 'Error',
                description: 'Failed to update settings, try again.',
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <HelmetWrapper
                title={title}
                description={description}
            />

            <CustomCard className="w-full" title={title} description={description}>
                <div className='faded-bottom -mx-4 flex-1 overflow-auto scroll-smooth  px-4 md:pb-16'>
                    <div className="w-full xl:w-[80%] h-full">
                        <div className="mt-5 w-full pb-12">
                            <FormProvider {...form}>
                                <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                    {generalData?.settings?.map((generalField, index) => {
                                        const error = formState.errors[generalField?.name]?.message;

                                        return (
                                            <div key={index} className='grid grid-cols-10 w-full gap-2 md:gap-8'>
                                                <div className='col-span-10 lg:col-span-6'>
                                                    <div
                                                        className='flex flex-col lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:justify-between gap-4 w-full'>
                                                        <FormLabel className="w-48">{generalField?.name}</FormLabel>

                                                        {generalField?.type === "text" && (
                                                            <FormInput
                                                                className="w-full my-3"
                                                                name={generalField?.name}
                                                                form={form}
                                                                debounceDelay={500}
                                                                error={error}
                                                            />
                                                        )}
                                                        {generalField?.type === "file" && (
                                                            <FormField
                                                                control={form.control}
                                                                name={generalField?.name}
                                                                render={({field}) => (
                                                                    <FormItem className="w-full my-3">
                                                                        <FormControl>
                                                                            <Input
                                                                                id="picture"
                                                                                type="file"
                                                                                placeholder="thumbnail"
                                                                                onChange={(e) => {
                                                                                    setThumbnail(e.target.files[0]);
                                                                                }}
                                                                            />
                                                                        </FormControl>
                                                                        <FormMessage/>
                                                                    </FormItem>
                                                                )}
                                                            />
                                                        )}

                                                        {generalField?.type === "radio" && (
                                                            <RadioGroup
                                                                value={selectedValues[generalField.name] || form.watch(generalField.name) || ""}
                                                                onValueChange={(value) => {
                                                                    handleRadioChange(generalField.name, value);
                                                                }}
                                                                className="flex items-center gap-3 mt-2 md:mt-4"
                                                            >
                                                                {manageOptions(generalField.options_data)?.map((option, idx) => (
                                                                    <div key={idx}
                                                                         className="flex items-center space-x-2 mb-2">
                                                                        <RadioGroupItem value={option.value}/>
                                                                        <Label>{option.label}</Label>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                ))}
                                                            </RadioGroup>
                                                        )}

                                                        {generalField?.type === "select" && (
                                                            <FormSelect2
                                                                className="w-full my-3"
                                                                name={generalField?.name}
                                                                form={form}
                                                                options={manageOptions(generalField?.options_data)}
                                                                placeholder="Select an option"
                                                            />
                                                        )}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div
                                                    className="col-span-10 lg:col-span-4 flex items-center text-gray-600">
                                                    <p className="text-[12px] text-gray-400">{generalField?.description}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })}

                                    <div className="mt-4">
                                        <Button type="submit">Save Settings</Button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </FormProvider>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </CustomCard>
        </>
    );
}



I want to update multiple fields in a form using GraphQL mutations, but I need to call the API once for all fields when the form is submitted, not for each individual field.
Currently, the API is being called separately for each field (like text, file, radio, etc.). How can I optimize this and ensure the API is only called once for all updates in the form?
